# What is the number of expressions containing n pairs of matching brackets with nesting limit?

Tags: formal-languages, combinatorics, recurrence-relation, word-combinatorics

I know the answer *without* nesting limit is the Catalan number. My question is, specifically, is there a recurrence relation that gives the number of expression containing $n$ pairs of matching brackets such that no more than $l$ open brackets are not closed at any given point?

For instance, for $n=3$ and $l=2$ the answer is $4$. All possible combinations are $(())()$, $()(())$, $()()()$, $(()())$. We cannot have $((()))$ since there are three open brackets that are not closed at the middle.

Answer (score 5):

Okay. I think I may have figured it out myself. I invite everyone to check my answer to see if it makes sense. So the first bracket must be a left bracket and there must be some right bracket later on that corresponds to this first bracket. Inside these two brackets there is a valid bracket expression $A$ with depth at most $l-1$ and outside these two brackets there is another valid expression $B$ with depth at most $l$ (since it is not already contained in a pair of brackets like $A$). Also, just like the definition of Catalan numbers, if $n=0$ then the number of valid expressions is $1$. If $n\neq 0$ and $l=0$ then the number of valid expressions is $0$ (since if $n\neq 0$ then we must have at least one pair of brackets, but $l=0$ means that we cannot have more than $0$ open bracket at any time, meaning that there is no way we can construct any valid bracket expressions). So the recurrence relation I got is:
\begin{align}
C(i, j)= \begin{cases}
1 & i=0 \\
0 & i\neq 0, j=0 \\
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i-1} C(k, j-1)\cdot C(i-k-1, j) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Haha, I overkilled. This looks good. Do you want to solve it, too?

Comment: What does solving mean?

Comment: Solving the recurrence, that is finding a closed form for $C(i,j)$.

Comment: Is there actually a closed form for this recurrence? I am not actually very good at solving recurrences and I can only solve some basic ones. So would you mind solving the recurrence, if possible?

Comment: It probably has; whether we can find it is another question. There are some methods you can employ, but this is not a straightforward recurrence. I'll ask some experts.

Comment: So would the running time of this algorithm be $O(n^3)$?

Comment: Using a memoisation matrix, $O(n^3)$ time and O$(n^2)$ space, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is not an easy problem, but it has been solved. A similar case is treated in [Bounded discrete walks](http://www.dmtcs.org/dmtcs-ojs/index.php/proceedings/article/view/dmAM0103) by Banderier and Nicodème (2010) and they refer to the exact result you need in [Combinatoire analytique des chemins et des cartes](http://lipn.fr/~banderier/Papers/these.ps)¹ by Banderier (2001).

---

1. This is a preliminary version. You can obtain a copy of the final version by [contacting the author](http://lipn.fr/~banderier/#Research).

Answer (score 1):

A comment and a suggestion.

For *fixed* $\ell$ the language of words with nesting limit $\ell$ is regular, with a very simple automaton, basically a line of states, each representing the current level. Form that automaton a recurrence formula can be obtained (in terms of the number of bracket pairs $n$, again for fixed $\ell$).

Your own formula reminds of the classical formula for Catalan numbers, using *convolution* $C_{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n C_iC_{n-i}$. 
Convolution is a nice operation when the sequence is presented as generating function, a formal infinite "polynomial"; for Catalan numbers $C(x) = \sum_{n\ge0} C_nx^n$. From the given recurrence one obtains $\frac {C(x)-1}x = C(x)^2$ from which experts can solve $C_n$.

In your formula you have an expression for $C_{\ell+1}(x)$ and $C_{\ell}(x)$, the generating functions for $\ell+1$ and $\ell$ bounded expressions. To me it seems [I might have errors here] that your formula is $\frac {C_{\ell+1}(x)-1}x = C_{\ell+1}(x)C_{\ell}(x)$. That is a recurrence relation for $C_\ell(x). Not in the numbers themselves, but in their generating functions.

Answer (score 0):

The question comes down to: how many ways are there to distribute $n$ nodes into subtrees? This is related to [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_partitions); in fact, this recurrence describes the desired quantity:

$\qquad \displaystyle \begin{align}
  a(1,1) &= 1 \\
  a(n,1) &= 0 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad, n>1 \\
  a(n,l) &= \sum_{P \in \operatorname{Part}(n)} \prod_{i \in P} a(i,l-1) \qquad, n,l > 1
\end{align}$

with $\operatorname{Part}(n)$ the set of all partitions (as multi-sets) of $n$. Well, that does not seem to be too approachable.

A more promising avenue might be via grammars and their generating function. For fixed $l \in \mathbb{N}_+$, the (unambiguous) grammar $G_l = (\{S_i \mid 0 \leq i \leq l \},\{(,)\},\delta_l, S_l)$ with $\delta_l$ given by

$\qquad \displaystyle \begin{align}
  S_0 &\to \varepsilon  \\
  S_i &\to (S_{i-1})S_i \mid \varepsilon \qquad, 0<i\leq l
\end{align}$

generates the [Dyck-language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) restricted to nesting depth $l$. This translates to the equation system

$\qquad \displaystyle \begin{align}
  S_0(z) &= 1 \\
  S_i(z) &= z^2S_{i-1}(z)S_i(z) + 1 \qquad, 0<i\leq l
\end{align}$

and $[z^n]S_l(z)$, that is the $n$-th coefficient of the series expansion of $S_l$ (around $z=0$), is the number of such words of length $n$. See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2329/98) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1091/98) for other examples of this technique with references.

For every fixed $l$, solving this system is easily done by computer algebra. I will have to ask around whether there are techniques to solve it in $l$; I know that similar cases have been [solved before](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X98000730).

Comment: Is there a good book from which I can learn what you wrote above (i.e. integer partitions, generating function etc.)?

Comment: @AdenDong: I have no expertise in number theory myself (maybe search/ask on [math.SE]?). For generating functions, see [generationfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) by Wilf and [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html) by Flajolet and Sedgewick. For the specific technique regarding grammars, have a look at the references I give in the linked answers.