# How to show that given language is unambiguous

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-free, proof-techniques, ambiguity

Given following grammar:

$$
\begin{align}
S \rightarrow &A1B \\
A \rightarrow & 0A \mid \varepsilon \\
B \rightarrow & 0B \mid 1B \mid \varepsilon \\
\end{align}
$$

How can I show that this grammar is unambiguous? I need to find a grammar for the same language that is ambiguous, and demonstrate it.

I know if I was asked to prove that the language is ambigious then I should find two different parse trees for same string, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-to-prove-that-a-grammar-is-unambiguous).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show a grammar is unambiguous you have to argue that for each string in the language there is only one derivation tree.

In this particular case you can observe that $A$ only generates $0$'s, so the $1$ generated by the start symbol $S$ must be the first $1$ in the string.

Any grammar can be made ambiguous by adding chain productions like $S\to S$.

Comment: so if i search an unambiguity over a language i should check if there exists any chain production whatever it is ? and by the way thanks for your reply.

Comment: For ambiguity you try to fiund one string with at least two parse trees (derivation trees). A chain production has the form $A\to A$. If such a production exists and $A$ occurs in the tree, you can find another tree by just adding $A\to A$. This will not change the word generated. And, no, it does not suffice to check for these productions. There might also be more general causes for ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

This grammar is equivalent with
$$
\begin{align}
S \rightarrow &0A1B\mid 1B \\
A \rightarrow & 0A \mid \varepsilon \\
B \rightarrow & 0B \mid 1B \mid \varepsilon \\
\end{align}
$$
and so *like* a simple grammar we can show that this grammar is not ambiguous. Of course this grammar is not simple.

Comment: What exactly is a »simple gramar«? Do you mean »regular grammar«?

Comment: a grammar G is said to be simple, if all productions are of the form $$ A \rightarrow ax $$ where $A\in V, a\in T,x\in V^\ast$, and any pair $(A,a)$ occurs at most once in productions.

Comment: Are the $\varepsilon$ productions allowed in simple grammars?