# A DFA recognizing my name

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata, proof-techniques

How can I know if my DFA is implemented correctly?
For example, I need to build a DFA, and then minimize it which will recognize my name.
Language which describe my name is:
L = {pustai, marius}

I came with this solution:

```
>(0)--p-->(1)--u-->(2)--s-->(3)--t-->(4)--a-->(5)--i-->(6)(goto state 0)
  |
 (7)--m-->(8)--a-->(9)--r-->(10)--i-->(11)--u-->(12)--s-->((13)) (final state)
```

How can I know if this is implemented correctly?
And about minimization of this automate I think is impossible.

Comment: This is not a DFA since it seems one can go from state 0 to state 7 without any input, though it is close to a DFA. Also, it repeats your last name an arbitrary number of times (including zero), before going to your fist name. It does not correspond to your definition of L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write down *all* accepting paths, that is paths from the starting state to final states. These are all the words the given automaton can accept; if the set is the desired one, q.e.d.

This is only possible and a rigorous proof for (co-)finite languages. Once you have cycles you have to apply induction. See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg) for an in-depth explanation on how to do this for grammars; it's similar for automata.