# Why is this language not context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, pumping-lemma

I been watching tutorials about how to check if a language is not context-free and in 1 video there was a language: L = {a^n b^n c^n | n ≥ 0} and they used a pumping lemma to prove that it's not context-free, I am only a beginner at CFG however I thought a language is Context-free if you are able to create a CFG for it, and this is the CFG i created for this language:

```
S --> aSX |  
X --> bXY | 
Y --> cY |
```

Or am I not understand CFG and what I wrote doesn't make sense?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! We get asked this sort of question a lot, so we've written some 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
I think you'll find it helpful to work through the related questions listed there.  See especially http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11315/755.  Hint: try to prove your CFG is correct using the methods in the latter question; I think you'll discover for yourself what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar you wrote can generate the word "aaa", which is not supposed to be generated, if the grammar generates exactly $L$.

ergo, the grammar is incorrect for $L$. (which is great, since $L$ is not CFL, and no grammar can generate it!)

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot about the epsilon, so even if the input aaabbbccc could theoretically be generated nothing stops you from supplying aaa, either, thanks for that