# Show that a language cannot be generated by linear grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I have a language $ L= \{ w \in \{a,b\}^* ; |w|_b=2i, i \ge 0 \}$  that is a language with even number of b's.

I found a grammar for it with these rules:

$S \rightarrow aS \ | \ bL \ | \ \lambda  $

$L \rightarrow aL \ | \ bS \  $

How could I show that this language cannot be generated by linear grammar?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar), a linear grammar is a context-free grammar that has at most one nonterminal in the right hand side of its productions.

Comment: Where did you find that definition?

Comment: Sorry, my lecturer had bad defintion in slides, I edited it, But still, this language is not regular, and I think its not linear too.

Comment: "this language is not regular" -- wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your grammar is right-regular and can thus be used to [prove](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg) that $L \in \mathrm{REG}$. Since every regular grammar is linear, your claim is impossible to prove.

Comment: My intuition says this language is not regular, so I'm trying to prove its not linear either ( regular $\ne$ linear )

Comment: @martinerk0 Your intuition is wrong, and contradicts your statement "I found a [regular] grammar for [$L$]".

Comment: Why would that grammar be regular?

Comment: It's right-regular; just check the definition. It's trivial to transform it into a DFA.

Answer (score 1):

A grammar whose only rules are of the form $X \to uYv$ and $X \to w$, where $u,v,w$ are terminals, can only generate words of odd length. Your language also contains words of even length. If you also allow rules of the form $X \to \epsilon$, then you can construct a grammar for your language (exercise).

Comment: I apologize, now I have correct definition of linear grammar.