# Prove L = L(R) based on a regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I'm given the following language:

`L = {w∈{0,1}* | w ends in 010 and contains 011}`

The task is to find a regular expression R that describes this language and prove L = L(R).

I have found the regular expression : `^([011])[01]*010$`.

But have no idea how to prove L=L(R)?

Comment: What definition (i.e. syntax and semantics) of "regular expression" are you working with? Your expression doesn't really comply with textbook notations.

Comment: We have a reference question that covers your problem in detail:
http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg

I strongly recommend you to refrain from using the PCRE notation when  talking about regular expressions in a non-programming context. In particular, subpatterns allow to form expressions that can define non-regular languages (not even context-free, in fact.)

Comment: @quicksort That question covers how to prove that a language is produced by some grammar, not how to prove that it matches some regular expression. I suppose one could convert the regular expression to a grammar, first, but that seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You are absolutely right, I'm very sorry. I assume my brain automatically accepted it after seeing "induction". Still, I believe our other reference questions provide a good coverage.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression you propose it seems you require the string to start with `011` rather than have it as an arbitrary substring.

So in my dialect of RegEx the expression would be `(0+1)*011(0+1)*010`. By definition that would specify all strings of the form $u 011 v 010$ where $u,v$ are arbitrary. This means all those strings have `011` as subword and end in `010`.

We also have to explain the converse. That every string with that subword and suffix is covered by the expression. For that it suffices to note that `011` and `010` cannot overlap. So, `010` must come before `011`. Which means it is of the form  $u 011 v 010$.