# Describing language generated by grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

S -> aSb | A | B

A -> aS | a

B -> Sb | b

is this the language generated by this CFG? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried towards proving your claim? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: [Quasi-duplicate reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg).

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: I tried different combinations of what I can get from this CFG, and it turned out to be something like: {a, b, ab, aba, abab, ba, baba} etc. hence the claim.

Answer (score 0):

A technique that can be useful here is to eliminate some of the variables. Since $A$ can only be replaced by $aS$ or $a$ and $B$ by $Sb$ or $b$ we have the equivalent grammar
$$
S\rightarrow aSb\mid aS\mid a\mid Sb\mid b
$$
Now notice that in any sentential form in a derivation we can only add $a$s to the left of $S$ and we can only add $b$s to the right, so any string of terminals derived from the start variable must have the form $a^mb^n$. Finishing off, we see that $S$ must eventually be replaced by one of $a$ or $b$, so we see that your proposed answer was almost correct:
$$
L(G) = \{a^mb^n\mid m,n\ge 0\text{ and }m,n\text{ not both }0\}
$$
or, if you prefer a slightly nonstandard regular expression-ish version
$$
a^*b^*\setminus\epsilon
$$