# Is the language of all non-palindromes context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Is the language $L = \{ w \mid w \in (a,b)^* \wedge w \text{ is not a palindrome} \}$, context-free? I think this grammar:

$
S \rightarrow aSa \mid bSb \mid aAb \mid bAa\\
A \rightarrow aAa \mid bAb \mid aAb \mid bAa \mid a \mid b \mid aa \mid ab \mid ba \mid bb
$

generates it, but I'm unable to conclude anything using the pumping lemma for context free languages.

Comment: I don't understand the "but" here. If you have a grammar, [prove it correct](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg) and done. Why would you be surprised that the Pumping lemma proof doesn't work if you think the language is context-free?

Answer (score 2):

If $w$ is not a palindrome then there must be some $i$ such that the $i$th letter from the left is different from the $i$th letter form the right; and vice versa (prove!). This means that
$$
L = \{ \Sigma^{i-1} a \Sigma^* b \Sigma^{i-1} : i \geq 1 \} \cup \{ \Sigma^{i-1} b \Sigma^* a \Sigma^{i-1} : i \geq 1 \},
$$
which is easily seen to be context-free.

Your grammar almost manages to capture this characterization. Unfortunately, it doesn't generate the words $ab$ and $ba$. A simpler grammar is
$$
\begin{align*}
&S \to aSa|bSb|aTb|bTa \\
&T \to aT|bT|\epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks, your grammar is way simpler than mine, but I think the idea is the same. Actually your grammar is a type-0  grammar due to that $\varepsilon$-transition, I wonder if you can make it without that.

Comment: My grammar is context-free (some people disallow $\epsilon$ transitions so that a CFG would automatically be a CSG, but that's not the only choice possible). It is, however, extremely simple to get rid of the $\epsilon$ production. The resulting grammar is $S\to aSa|bSb|aTb|bTa|ab|ba$, $T\to aT|bT|a|b$.

Comment: My teacher always asks to make grammars without $\varepsilon$ productions, I think that's a good exercise.