# Is this language equivalent to this grammar?

Tags: formal-grammars

[image]

The book that I'm reading says it is equivalent

But what about the **aa** string ? i produce it this way :

$$
S\Rightarrow S_1B\Rightarrow aS_1bB\Rightarrow aaB\Rightarrow aa
$$
But that language doesn't have aa in it, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you please replace the image with text?

Comment: Is it common to typeset one and zero like that?

Comment: Your derivation is correct. If you quoted correctly, the book is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: You can [try proving the claim](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg) and see how it goes.

Comment: Unless I missed something, $L=\{a^nb^{n+2(k-1)}\mid n\ge 2, k\ge 0\}$

Comment: Which text did you draw this from? I will research and post. But I agree the grammar and the language def do not agree.