# Are the regular expressions equivalent?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Is the following equivalence true?

$$(r_1^*r_2^*)^* = (r_1 + r_2)^*$$

I think these are equivalent since both the expressions generate the same strings: $\{\epsilon,r_1,r_2,\dots\}$ etc.

Comment: What are $r_1$ and $r_2$?

Comment: Any alphabet. Like $r_1$ = a and $r_2$ = b @Gribouillis

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. The expressions denote the same language for every language $r_1$ and $r_2$. This can be shown using finite state automata: [Regular expression $(a^{*}b^{*})^{*} = \left( a+b \right)^{*}$ proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/82212/regular-expression-ab-left-ab-right-proof) Alternatively there is Kleene algebra which has equational rules that characterize regular expression equivalence.

Comment: @HendrikJan Ah, thanks! That clears up my confusion!