# Does this grammar generate regular language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

$S \rightarrow AB$

$A \rightarrow aA \mid bA \mid \epsilon$

$B \rightarrow aBb \mid \epsilon$

Does this grammar generate regular language?

According to me this grammar generates language of the form 
$$
L = \{ (a+b)^* a^nb^n \mid n\ge 1\}
$$

I think it's a DCFL. If the condition would have been $n\ge0$ then it's regular according to me. But my book says it's regular language.

Am I correct ?

Comment: Why do you think $n\ge 1$?

Comment: @RickDecker if n≥0 then all words, no matter how you pump them, are contained inside (a + b)* and belong to the language

Comment: @rotia Correct. However, the OP said "According to me this grammar generates ... $n\ge 1". I wondered why.

Comment: @RickDecker true, I didn't look at the grammar, you are right

Comment: The language of $B$ is *not* regular. What's your regular grammar for it?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Why don't you try to prove your answer correct?  Then you'll know whether you are correct.  You might start with https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11315/755, then try to find a DFA or regular grammar for your language -- see https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755 -- then try to find a deterministic PDA for it.

Comment: @Rick Decker, Is it n>=0 because S (start symbol) is able to generate epsilon ? if it would have been n>=1 then it would be DCFL right ?

Comment: It is $n\ge 0$ since that's what $B$ can generate. If it had been the production $B\rightarrow aBa\mid ab$, then it would have generated $a^nb^n$ for $n\ge 1$

Comment: So for $n>=1$, it would be CFL and not DCFL right ? It would not be regular as we no longer have $epsilon$ in $a^n b^n$ which can help us to generate $(a+b)^*$ . Am I correct ? @Rick Decker.

Comment: How will it be regular ? Language also contains strings like aabb aabb which do not end with ab. I think epsilon matters.

Comment: @Rick Decker. !!

Comment: @RickDecker OP is right, set $w=a^pb^p$ then xy contains only a's, then set i=0, since y is bigger or equal than 1, we have less a's than b's

Comment: I neglected the $n$s when I wrote "ending in $ab$". My bad.

Comment: @rotia So it would be CFL right ?