# Removing epsilon transition from the grammar. What's the difference between accepting languages?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I want to remove the epsilon transition from following grammar:
\begin{eqnarray}
S & \rightarrow & A | B \\
A & \rightarrow & \epsilon \\ 
B & \rightarrow &  aBa \\
B & \rightarrow & b \\
\end{eqnarray}
This is the result of removing $\epsilon$ transition:
\begin{eqnarray}
S & \rightarrow & \epsilon | B \\
B & \rightarrow & aBa \\
B & \rightarrow & b
\end{eqnarray}

My question is what's the difference between languages that accept these two grammars?

Comment: If you followed the algorithm, there is provably no difference. Try [proving that](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg).

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Both grammars describe the same language $$L = \{ \epsilon \} \cup \{ a^nba^n  | \forall n > 0\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

No difference. You can't *re-choose* the terminal $A$ after choosing it even once in your example.