# How to produce a context free grammar for this language?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I've already attempted it but I am finding it difficult to understand if this is correct.

give a context free grammar for the following:

$$ \{p^{3m+n}q^nr^2p^m\mid m,n\ge 0 \}$$

The answer i've attempted is:
$S \to XY$
$X \to pppXp \mid \ q$
$Y \to qYr \mid \epsilon$

I've been trying to understand if i need to break down:
$$ \{p^{3+m+n} \}$$ in to

$$ \{p^{3}p^m p^n \}$$

to give me: pppXp

then q and r would value to

qYr | $\epsilon$

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science!  Have you tried [proving your grammar correct](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg)? (Lanugage note: you don't "solve a grammar".)

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to figure out a context-free grammar for some simple languages is to find, by peeling off terminals, smaller and smaller languages that are nicely structured such that if you use a nonterminal to represent each smaller language, you can restore the larger languages from the smaller ones with a production rule.

$S=\{p^{3m+n}q^nr^2p^m\mid m,n\ge 0 \}$

If you peel off $p^3$ from the front and $p$ from the back $m$ times, you got language $B=\{p^nq^nr^2\mid n\ge 0 \}$. Can you see how to produce $S$ from $B$ by one production rule? In fact, that is part of what you have written.

Peeling off $r^2$ at the end, you get language $C=\{p^nq^n\mid n\ge 0 \}$. Can you get $B$ from $C$? Can you produce/recall a context-free grammar for $C$?

Comment: for C it would be just C -> pXq

Comment: Correct. Or, in fact, $C->pCq\mid \epsilon$.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, as the asker, you can accept an answer if it helps and if you want to say thanks.

Comment: I've attempted a final answer and i got: S -> XccY, X -> nXh | nX |  ϵ , Y -> n

Comment: The answer to your original image should look like $S\to nAn$, $A\to Bc$, $B\to nBh$. Can you see the peeling off at each level?