# Regular expressions

Tags: regular-expressions

I am new to theoretical cs and am working through it slowly. I have completed a simple question and was wondering if my answer is correct or not. Thank you kindly for any feedback.

**The question is:**
Given the alphabet $\{a, b\}$
Construct a regular expression that defines the language $M$ containing all words beginning with exactly one $a$ or exactly one $b$. Words in $M$ are at least of length $1$. Words in $M$ can begin and end with the same letter substring or begin and end with different letter substrings.

**My answer is:**
$( a( b( a + b)^*)^*) + (b ( a (a + b)^*)^*)$

Thank you.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11315/755

Comment: (`working through [CS] slowly` Exactly what [Donald Knuth set out to do](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming).)

Comment: (There have been discussions [What to do when the answer is already part of the question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-to-do-when-the-answer-is-already-part-of-the-question).)

Comment: Yeah thanks I came here as last resort namely because I don't really have teachers or class mates as such. I just do the work and submit it. Thanks anyway I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $A = a + b$, you could write $M$ as $A + abA^* + baA^*$ or as $A + (ab +ba)A^*$. This avoids the nested star of your answer.