# Context-free grammar for $a^{2n} b^{2n}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I have just started learning formal languages and here is a question I am facing a little hurdle:

> Construct a context-free grammar for $\{ a^{2n}b^{2n} \mid n \ge 0 \}$.

This was what I got at first.
$$S \to ab\mid aS\mid Sb\mid ab$$
Now I am getting this,
$$S\to \epsilon$$

$$S\to aaSbb$$

$$G=(V,\Sigma,R,S)=(\{S,a,b\},\{a,b\},R,S)$$

$$R= \{S \to aaSbb\mid \epsilon\}$$
Is the approach to this question, right or is it done in a different way?

Comment: Evidently not, because the desired language has an even number of `a`s and an even number of `b`s, while your proposed grammar immediately derives a string (`ab`) which does not have an even number of anything (through two different productions, which is redundant).

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11315/755

Answer (score 1):

Here is a derivation in your grammar:

$$ S \to aS \to aab. $$

The word $aab$ does not belong to your language, hence your grammar is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the solution:
$$S\to \epsilon \mid aaSbb $$

Answer (score -1):

the second grammer you wrote, is right.
it can involve all strings belongs to the language with no extra string.

Comment: We'd prefer answers that come with explanation, justification, and/or proof of correctness.  We want to share not just the correct answer but information that will help others figure out how to obtain that answer or how to know that it is correct.