# Find an unambiguous grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

S → aS | aSbS | (empty)
where the alphabet is {a,b}

in other words, the set of strings where any prefix has at least as many 'a's as 'b's.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? It is not clear at all. You have given a grammar that does not do what you specify.

Comment: sry about the typo! i gave an ambiguous grammar of that. what's an unambiguous one for it?

Answer (score 1):

A grammar that can do this unambiguously is:

$S \to aS \mid A S \mid \epsilon$
$A \to a AAb \mid \epsilon$

Every b is associated with an a in front of it, and anything between these is also associated in the same way so there is always balance.

Comment: Proof of [either](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg) [claim](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-to-prove-that-a-grammar-is-unambiguous?rq=1)?